# Jcarouselite object seems to behave like it has position:fixed when the window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to describe the issue better.  Here is a link to the site with the issue.

http://www.sc-pa.com/Home/PAsite-home.asp

expand or shrink the window horizontally and you will see the scrolling text doesn't move correctly with the rest of the window.

Ignore the menu, it was written in Dreamweaver and doesn't work well ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for `IE relative becoming fixed` and found http://friendlybit.com/css/ie6-resize-bug/

I downloaded your page, saw the bug in IE8 indeed, and added `position:relative;` to the body element and the issue was fixed.

[image]

Comment: how about that the WHOLE site is written like this...Response.write "</td></tr><tr><td align=center>".  I've got a lot to fix.  The head of my organization reported the issue on IE8.  So I have to fix the scroller issue.

Comment: grr forgot enter adds comments. Found the solution and updated post :)

Comment: also thanks for showing what you searched on.  I had no idea how to accurately describe this problem.